# Apache vHosts - Two domains, multiple subdomains and defaults possible?

Tags: virtualhost, redirect, apache2, subdomain

after searching and try-and-erroring for a while I came to the conclusion that my problem is a bit too special for google :-)

I have 2 domains and multiple subs

**example.org**

- cloud.example.org
- wiki.example.org
- *.example.org (all other to this domain) should redirect to example.org which shows the "under construction" image.

**beispiel.de**

- blog.beispiel.de
- same here: *.beispiel.de should redirect to beispiel.de

I have 1 file per subdomain with 1 vHost in my Apache conf.
I use "Let's encrypt" for https.

Problems:

http://blupp.example.com goes to http**s**://blupp.example.com and Firefox shows the connection not secure warning. After klicking Ignore, it redirects to the main page but with https://blupp.example.com in the URL.

-> **Error** It should go to example.com

Another Problem is:

example.com is my first page. So if sth. goes wrong at beispiel.de, it redirects to the first page: cloud.example.com

-> **Error** I dont want to mix example.com and beispiel.de, but only want to rent one server :-)

These are my files (order is important, I know :-)

**0_redirects.conf**
Just make http requests -> https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule "/" https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>
```

**1_cloud-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin admin@... 
    ServerName cloud.example.com
    ServerAlias cloud.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/cloud/>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf  

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Same for **wiki.example.com** and **blog.beispiel.de**, each with an incremented prefix number.

I first tried to get all example.com pages running, so I left beispiel.de untouched.

Now I tried many ways to create an additional vHost for both main domains that redirects evrything else to the correct main **example** or **beispiel**, but failed.

I tried to redirect

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName null
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect permanent / example.com

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and set this config on a higher order position (100).

I don't know what to do here.
Can someone help?

Best regards

Eddi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to have your redirects working correctly for each sub-domain is to set them up in their own `VirtualHost` containers.

The second thing is to not use a parameterised mod_rewrite rule for your redirects, but as the manual recommends [avoid mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) and use [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directives.

```
# Correctly redirect plain http requests -> https


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cloud.example.org
    Redirect "/" "https://cloud.example.org/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wiki.example.org
    Redirect "/" "https://wiki.example.org/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias *.example.org
    Redirect "/" "https://example.org/"
</VirtualHost>
```

and similarly for `biespiel.de`.

Take into account that for Apache HTTPD ServerName and ServerAlias matching is dependant on order and that first-match will be used with regards to Host: headers that match multiple VirtualHosts.  No special priority is made for ServerAlias records containing a wildcard `*`. Therefore the explicit  `ServerName cloud.example.org` VirtualHosts  must be ordered before VirtualHost block containing the `ServerAlias *.example.org` wildcard.

Comment: Thanks, HBruijn,

I will test it tonight
So can I  put the *:80 directives into my 0_redirects.conf file and use a single file for each *:433 vHost?

Comment: Thanks, HBruijn again. It worked for both domains and all subdomains. It took me months, LOL... sometimes the less complicated solution is the best